# Error installing Laser scan tools for ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install Laser scan tools from  git clone https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools.git, on Hydro.  Every time I try to run Catkin_make, I get an error:

```
[ 41%] Performing configure step for 'csm_src'
-- Create a file named 'local_config/local-brent-Dell-DM051.cmake' if you want to add options.
gsl home: 
DBG GSL_CONFIG GSL_CONFIG-NOTFOUND
FATAL_ERROR,FindGSL.cmake: gsl-config not found. Please set it manually. GSL_CONFIG=GSL_CONFIG-NOTFOUND
CMake Error at sm/CMakeLists.txt:30 (MESSAGE):
  GSL not found.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make[2]: *** [scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher/csm/stamp/csm_src-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher/CMakeFiles/csm_src.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX executable /home/brent/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ncd_parser/ncd_parser
[ 41%] Built target ncd_parser
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195435/error-installing-laser-scan-tools-for-ros/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the typical error that you get from CMake when it can't find a package.

In this particular case, the package it can't find is GSL.

You can try installing GSL with `sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev`.

More generally, you can install all of the dependencies for your workspace with rosdep:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src -i
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-10-21**:
Worked perfect!  Thank you!